# SQL INSERT query being executed twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I'm at my wit's end here. I've tried in all different browsers and still get the same trigger error message `Notice: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'` However, it's still inserting into the database. I think the page is simultaneously executing twice. The code never reaches the block where it stores the session data. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
            <?php               
                if($_POST[submit])
                {                   
                    $username = "";
                    $password = "";
                    $hostname = "";
                    $dbname = "";

                    //connection to the database:
                    $db = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname, '3306')
                    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

                    $id = !empty($_POST[id]) ? "'$_POST[id]'" : "NULL";
                    $fname = !empty($_POST[fname]) ? "'$_POST[fname]'" : "NULL";
                    $lname = !empty($_POST[lname]) ? "'$_POST[lname]'" : "NULL";    

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO Table(id, fname, lname)
                                VALUES ($id, $fname, $lname)";

                    $result = $db->query($sql) OR trigger_error($db->error);

                    if ($result && $db->affected_rows > 0)
                    {
                        // store session data
                        $_SESSION['fileid']=$id;
                        echo 'Creating file '.$id.'<br/>
                            <a href = "partTwo.php" class="button">Continue</a>';
                    }
                    else
                        echo "No changes made.";
                }               
                else 
                    echo '<form method="post" action="createFile.php">
                            <div><span class = "formlabel">File number:</span><input type="Text" name="id"></div>
                            <div><span class = "formlabel">First name:</span><input type="Text" name="fname"></div>
                            <div><span class = "formlabel">Last name:</span><input type="Text" name="lname"></div>
                            <input class="submit" type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>';
            ?>
```

Comment: did you define the $username = "";
                    $password = "";
                    $hostname = "";
                    $dbname = ""; in your scrip

Comment: Yes, They're defined in the script.

Comment: have you tried to add logging comments just before insert and just after insert? this is to see if the insert has been called twice..

Comment: clear your cache ...may be the id is repeating from cache..and try to hardcode values (not form form) to see if the insert works as well

Comment: @Sanath I just tried hardcoding the values. Still having same problem with duplicate entry error.

Comment: http://www.hesk.com/knowledgebase/?article=63

disable submit button after one click in case duplicate submissions are happening..

Comment: @Sanath disabling prevents GET/POST, so doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Let me know the results of $id,$fname,$lname,$result values when you do var_dump();

Comment: @Ruwantha `string(6) "'1234'" string(4) "NULL" string(4) "NULL" bool(false)`

Comment: The first problem is that your form is not parsing fname,lname values to the script. Then check you have defined a criteria in the database to not insert the null values to the fname and lname.make the Id field unique and auto increment in the database. And what is your table name ?

Comment: The problem that I'm having is that the insert statement is being executed twice. There is no problem with inserting values into the database. My form works fine, fname and lname can be null, that's fine. I am stuck at the Duplicate entry error. If anybody could shed some light on this, I would be thrilled!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `if($_POST[submit])` use `if(isset($_POST[submit]))`

Comment: @johnnyj oh..ok..let me once again check the whole

Comment: @johnnyj is that the id unique every time $id = !empty($_POST[id]) ? "'$_POST[id]'" : "NULL"; ECHO it(debug it basically)

Comment: @johnnyj can you please chck the values in you table ..like blank or NULL ..if it is clear it and then check..and let me know the case

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code and now it works well :)

```
     <?php               

        //connection to the database:

                            $username = "";
                            $password = "";
                            $hostname = "";
                            $dbname = "";
                            $db = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname, '3306')
                            or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

                        if(isset($_POST[submit]))
                        {                   

                           if(($id = !empty($_POST['id']) || $fname = !empty($_POST['fname']) || $lname = !empty($_POST['lname']))
    {
       echo "error msg.";
    }else{
    $id = "";
    $fname = "";
    $lname = "";   

                            $sql = "INSERT INTO Table(id, fname, lname)
                                        VALUES ($id, $fname, $lname)";

                            $result = $db->query($sql) OR trigger_error($db->error);
}

                            if ($result && $db->affected_rows > 0)
                            {
                                // store session data
                                $_SESSION['fileid']=$id;
                                echo 'Creating file '.$id.'<br/>
                                    <a href = "partTwo.php" class="button">Continue</a>';
                            }
                            else
                                echo "No changes made.";
                        }               
                        else 
                            echo '<form method="post" action="createFile.php">
                                    <div><span class = "formlabel">File number:</span><input type="Text" name="id"></div>
                                    <div><span class = "formlabel">First name:</span><input type="Text" name="fname"></div>
                                    <div><span class = "formlabel">Last name:</span><input type="Text" name="lname"></div>
                                    <input class="submit" type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                                </form>';
                    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the problem isn't addressed here.